# How to move arrows and close button within colorbox jquery popup?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to customize popup on the website: http://vmelab.com
Section: OUR PORTFOLIO
Once popup appears you will see something on the screenshot:
https://yadi.sk/i/1Y4OSXZvquTqw
I want to move arrows and close button to different places like it's shown on the screenshot. 
Which css attributes should I use?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
#cboxPrevious,
#cboxNext {
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin: auto
}
#cboxNext {
   right: 0;
   left: auto
}
#cboxClose {
   top: 0
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much!